# Does a certain family of subsets of S allow to always define a certain kind of equivalence relation on S?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $U_x$ be a subset of $\mathcal P(S)$ such that $x \in \cap U_x$: with the following properties:

$(1)\,\,\,U_x$ is nested: for all $X,Y \in U_x$ either $X \subseteq Y$ or $Y \subseteq X$.

$(2)\,\,\,U_x$ is closed under unions

$(3)\,\,\,U_x$ is closed under non-empty intersections

**Question:**
My question is whether the properties of $U_x$ alone are sufficient to define an equivalence relation---as in the example below---in order to induce a partition of $S$.

The kind of partition I have in mind can be exemplified on the assumption that $S$ is finite. If $S$ is finite then we can order its elements by natural numbers. So there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $U_x=\{X^0, X^1,...,X^n\}$ has the following form: $X^0 \subseteq X^1 \subseteq... \subseteq X^{n-1} \subseteq X^n$. This allows for the definition of the following equivalence relation on $S$: $\; y \sim_x z \;$ iff $\; \{y,z\}\subseteq X^k \setminus X^{k-1}$ for some $ 0\lt k\le n$. And the set $S/\sim_x$ is a partition of $S$.

Can this kind of partition be achieved in general, for any $S$ and $U_x$ with properties (1)-(3), or would some additional assumptions need to be made? By this *kind* I mean *all* elements of $U_x$ contributing in an orderly manner as in the given example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(1)$ needs attention, $X \subseteq Y$ is repeated.You wanted $X \subseteq Y$or $Y \subseteq X$

Comment: When you say "closed under unions", do you mean that if $A, B \in U_x$, then $A \cup B \in U_x$? Or do you mean arbitrary unions, perhaps including infinite ones? Same question for intersections.

Comment: Any family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $S$ whatsoever induces an equivalence relation on $S$: namely, $a\equiv b$ iff for all $X\in\mathcal{F}$, we have $a\in X\iff b\in X$. This agrees with the situation you've described. The ordering doesn't play any role here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MohammadRiazi-Kermani.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnHughes Arbitrary unions and intersections, i.e. for every $ \mathcal S \subseteq U_x$, $\cap \mathcal S \in U_x$. Same answer for non-empty intersections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $S = \Bbb R \cap [0, 1]$, $x = 1$. Define $X$ by 
$$
X = \{ [r, 1] \mid r \in S \}.
$$

In other words, $X$ consists of all intervals starting at a point in $S$, and ending at $1$. This is closed under unions and under intersections.

But your proposed equivalence relation fails completely in this case, for there is no "previous" set to subtract from $X^r$, i.e., nothing analogous to $X^k \setminus X^{k-1}$.

In this case, Noah's partition consists of all singleton sets (which I proposed as an answer to your earlier question on this topic).

Comment: Of course I'm aware that the equivalence relation I proposed will not work in general. I merely used a finite case to illustrate the idea. So pointing out that it doesn't work in an infinite case isn't very helpful. Yes you did say something about singleton sets as partitions, but the equivalence relation Noah gave will allow partitions that don't necessarily contain only singleton sets, accommodating for non-singleton equivalence classes, as the case will often be. I take his reply to be more illuminating.

Comment: Re: "of course": I have no idea what you know. Your proposed method *does* work fine for an infinite index like the integers. And Noah's method, applied to my example (that's what I meant by "In this case,") does produce singletons, as I claimed. But since you can't seem to say what you want, only that the things I've said *aren't* what you want, despite meeting all your criteria, I'm done. Also,  "the kind of partition" is just another sloppy way of saying "like what I've done", which is the very ambiguity I criticized in your earlier question. Perhaps someone who reads minds better can help.

Comment: I appreciate your help and time. Thank you.